# using ngfor inside div not showing results of restful api response

Tags: angular

I have RESTful api which provides results set like

```
{
    "count": 10,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Rocky (1976)",
            "description": "A small-time boxer gets a supremely rare chance to fight a heavy-weight champion in a bout in which he strives to go the distance for his self-respect.",
            "moviePoster": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pic_folder/no-poster.jpeg",
            "avg_rating": 5,
            "no_of_ratings": 1,
            "maxRatings": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Rocky (1976)",
            "description": "A small-time boxer gets a supremely rare chance to fight a heavy-weight champion in a bout in which he strives to go the distance for his self-respect.",
            "moviePoster": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pic_folder/no-poster.jpeg",
            "avg_rating": 3.5,
            "no_of_ratings": 2,
            "maxRatings": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside component.ts I have following method:

```
getMovies() {
this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(
  response => {
    this.movies= response.JSON;
    console.log('response.JSON',response);
  },
  error => {
    this.snackBar.open('Error getting Movies', '', { duration: 3000 });
  }
);
  }
```

I am trying to print "movie titles" in component.html and I have following div but nothing is getting printed on the html page.

```
 <div class="container">
 <h2>Movies:</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let movie of movies;" >
  <h4>{{movie.title}}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Your json doesn't seems to be a valid one, can you check again?

Comment: this.movie is array or object?

Comment: when you are calling this `getMovies()` method? on `ngOnInit()` or `constrcutor()` . can you check what is the output of `{{movies | json}}` on HTML

Comment: @diEcho getMovies() is inside ngOnInit() , I tried {{movies | json}} on HTML same thing nothing gets displayed "no error" in console

Comment: Why you are using `response.JSON` and not `response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this change

```
this.movieService
.getMovies()
.subscribe( (response) => { this.movies = response.results;},
```

Comment: perfect solutions!!